# Can frontend applications upload files directly to Google Cloud Storage without a middle tier?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to build a a web app that does some image/pdf processing. the intent is to allow users to upload a file and get some response back.

My frontend stack is React and I'm using GCP Storage along with cloud functions that run based on the notification from storage.

All examples that I find for uploading files to Google Storage are for NodeJS implementations with Express and so is their SDK. only references I see for web is via Firebase but I'm not sure I want to go that route. is there any other way to build such functionality without an express implementation?

Comment: If you already using Cloud Functions in your app, you can create a cloud function to handle the uploading file for your app. Here is the doc to handle multipart data in CF https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-form-data

Comment: but isn't it counterproductive? if my webapp needs to allow users to upload large files, what's the point of the frontend uploading them to a backend (or cloud function) that will store them in storage? what's the reason I cannot upload directly from frontend apps?

Answer (score 0):

Most of JS libraries can work on both NodeJS and the Browser (where your React app runs).

Sometimes instead libraries are tied to NodeJs only, or browser only. It depends on the runtime APIs they use (eg. "fs" module is available to NodeJS only)

Moreover, before uploading files you want to make sure your users are authenticated and have permissions to upload. So normally you have:

1. Mobile app authenticating users
2. Mobile app invoking your backend/function for upload passing auth token
3. Backend/function validating the request authentication token
4. Backend/function pushing the file to the storage (the backend/function itself needs to run using a service account that's allowed to write to the storage bucket)